# Android setVisibility function not working

Tags: java, android, xml

I have been trying to use the setVisibility() function for hours in the following code:

Here is the Adapter Class:

```
public class ExamScheduleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
private ArrayList<String> id;
private ArrayList<String> name;
private ArrayList<String> date, subject, total, passing;
private Activity context;

Button idview;
TextView nameview, dateview, subjectview, totalview, passview;

public ExamScheduleAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String>id, ArrayList<String>name, ArrayList<String>date) {
    super(context, R.layout.fragment_exam_shedule, id);
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.date = date;
    this.context = context;
}

public ExamScheduleAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String>id, ArrayList<String>name, ArrayList<String>date,
                           ArrayList<String>subject, ArrayList<String>total, ArrayList<String>passing) {
    super(context, R.layout.fragment_exam_shedule, id);
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.date = date;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.total = total;
    this.passing = passing;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listviewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_es,null,true);
    idview=(Button) listviewItem.findViewById(R.id.es_list_id);
    nameview=(TextView)listviewItem.findViewById(R.id.es_list_exam_name);
    dateview=(TextView)listviewItem.findViewById(R.id.es_list_date);

    subjectview=listviewItem.findViewById(R.id.es_list_exam_subject);
    totalview=listviewItem.findViewById(R.id.es_list_exam_t_marks);
    passview=listviewItem.findViewById(R.id.es_list_exam_p_marks);

    idview.setText(id.get(position));
    nameview.setText(name.get(position));
    dateview.setText(date.get(position));

    idview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(subjectview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                subjectview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                totalview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                passview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                subjectview.invalidate();
                totalview.invalidate();
                passview.invalidate();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Now visible", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                subjectview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                totalview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                passview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                subjectview.invalidate();
                totalview.invalidate();
                passview.invalidate();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Now invisible", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

    return listviewItem;
}
}
```

The layout for the customized list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/es_list_id"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Exam1"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/es_list_exam_name"
    android:hint="name"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_columnSpan="5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/es_list_date"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="2018-07-06"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="8"
    android:layout_columnSpan="3"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/es_list_exam_subject"
    android:hint="Hindi"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/es_list_exam_t_marks"
    android:hint="100"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="4"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/es_list_exam_p_marks"
    android:hint="35"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="8"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

</GridLayout>
```

The onclick function is being triggered and it is also being able to check for visibility as the toast message appears correctly ("Now visible" at first and then alternatively both the message on other clicks")
What could be the problem? I have tried every option. I did with invalidate, without invalidate, used view.gone, view.invisible etc, but nothing seems to work.

Plz help! Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you try using notifydataChanged ?

Comment: what is list_es here ?

Comment: looks like you did not understand how the listview works.

Answer (score 0):

Your `subjectview`, `totalview` and `passview` variables are scoped in the adapter and not in each adapter item. Hence the latest one adapter item that gets instantiated with `getView()` gets to overwrite those with their own values.

Change the variables to be local in `getView()` so that each `OnClickListener` gets its own copies of those.

Comment: If variables declared as local it is showing error(red underline) in the onclicklistener  for variables ,  Is there any other solution ???

Comment: Looks like you're on Java 7 and not on Java 8. Then the variable needs to explicitly `final`, too, to be passed to an anon inner class instance like your click listener.

Answer (score 0):

`getView()` method in the adapter is called to create each list item view shown on the screen. This way your code will each time overwrite your global variables

```
Button idview;
TextView nameview, dateview, subjectview, totalview, passview;
```

And you never know which list item views will it contain in the end.

Instead of declaring the global variables, use `final` local ones:

```
final Button idview=(Button) listviewItem.findViewById(R.id.es_list_id);
final TextView nameview=(TextView)listviewItem.findViewById(R.id.es_list_exam_name);
final TextView dateview=(TextView)listviewItem.findViewById(R.id.es_list_date);

final TextView subjectview=listviewItem.findViewById(R.id.es_list_exam_subject);
final TextView totalview=listviewItem.findViewById(R.id.es_list_exam_t_marks);
final TextView passview=listviewItem.findViewById(R.id.es_list_exam_p_marks);
```

(don't forget to remove)

```
Button idview;
TextView nameview, dateview, subjectview, totalview, passview;
```

Comment: I have tried it .It doesn't worked is there any other solution ?